# In gvim, change inner word (ciw) puts me in insert mode midway

Tags: vim, mode

Why does this happen in gvim:

- I'm in normal mode, and I want to replace a word, say "bat".
- I place the cursor on the "t".
- I try to type 'ciw', but as soon as I press the "i", it goes into insert mode and enters an i, such that the word becomes "bait".

Am I in some special mode? It works fine in regular vim.

Comment: Try it again but starting your vim without any config/plugins: `gvim -u NONE`

Answer (score 0):

Do all other commands work fine? Then, it's likely a bad mapping on `c`. You can check with

```
:verbose nmap c
```

From your description, it sounds like you have `:nmap c ii`.

Alternatively, you can also start GVIM without any personal config and plugins:

```
$ gvim -N -u NONE
```

Comment: Many other command don't work (e.g. diw). In fact, I can't string any command that involves multiple letters together without gvim interpreting each letter individually.

For the record, ':verbose nmap c' says "No mapping found", and the problem still happens when I start gvim using 'gvim -N -u NONE'. Crazy right? I'm running gvim on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, if that helps any.

Comment: @orochryden Strange indeed. Do you use any input method editor (Anthy, etc.) for non-ASCII characters? What's your keyboard layout, and does switching to a standard one (en-US) help? Do you see any additional keys when you trace keyboard input with `xev`?

Comment: Well, this is extremely embarrassing and unintuitive, but restarting my computer fixed the issue! I'm going to go ahead and delete my question because it's unlikely anyone would ever find this useful.

Comment: OK, this is embarrassing, but it was because Num Lock was enabled. Any idea why this would cause the issue?